# Create Custom Column data in analytics canvas

Tags: canvas, analytics, web-analytics

I'm a newbie in Analytics Canvas and I try to create a report where the first column in my sheet is the name of the source tables.

I have:

[image: My tables]

And the result of combined tables is:

[image: Result data of combined tables]

This is what I want but I don't know how to do:

[image: Look at first collumn this is what i need]

if anyone can help me i would be very happy

thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

To add the profile name and/or ID into the query, go to the "Additional data" tab in the query definition- there you will find a check box list with the following columns:

accountID, accountName, webPropertyID,profileID,profile,currency,timeZone, APIRequestStartDate and APIRequestEndDate

Just check the ones you want- in your example above it would be profileName